# How to find all refs that contain a commit in their history in git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-tag

Lets assume you have the following structure in git

```
    A <-- refs/heads/somebranch
    |
    B 
    | \
    C  D <-- refs/tags/TAG1
    |  |
    E  F
    |  | \
    G  H  I <-- refs/heads/branch1                
    |
    J <-- refs/heads/master
```

Now I want to find all refs that contain commit `B` in their history.

So it would be nice if I could do

```
$ git refs --contains B
refs/tags/TAG1
refs/heads/branch1
refs/heads/master
```

I took a look at the git decumentation and found `git branch -a --contains <commit_id>` which lists all branches that contain a `commit_id`.

```
$ git branch -a --contains 4af9822
  master
  remotes/origin/someBranch
  ...
```

and I found the command `git tag --contains 9338f2d`

```
$ git tag --contains 9338f2d
  someTag
  anotherTag
  ...
```

Of course I can do something like this,

```
$ git branch -a --contains 4af9822 && git tag --contains 9338f2d
```

but is there a command that prints all refs at once?

Comment: `git for-each-ref --contains` will be available only in 2.7 though ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To add to torek's answer, git 2.7 (Q4 2015) will offer a more complete version of [`git for-each-ref`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref), which now support the `--contains`

```
git for-each-ref --contains <SHA1>
```

---

See [commit 4a71109](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a71109aa442ba1a7045d36f6b148113c95ffc48), [commit ee2bd06](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee2bd06b0f735a00ce0216ca1d3391b13722d987), [commit f266c91](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f266c9163b34ec55e453d27e1ed246d67ee3ced0), [commit 9d306b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d306b5a6077f026291df3c4a5968eaf95a92417), [commit 7c32834](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c32834813bd6aee5ce5b2c4131d9f34249bc9e3), [commit 35257aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35257aa01203bae74f9fb856fb02c10c4b3836e6), [commit 5afcb90](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5afcb90560586765bf21fb09959a8b4497804639), [commit d325406](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d325406ef2f3c819d02ac838fb2a3f8e021d08ae), [commit 6841104](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68411046b5067de9c378d1f58313f2fae288286c), [commit b2172fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2172fdf702426cb4eba093b5504d0a0e9e59746), [commit b2172fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2172fdf702426cb4eba093b5504d0a0e9e59746), ..., [commit b2172fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2172fdf702426cb4eba093b5504d0a0e9e59746) (07 Jul 2015), and [commit af83baf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af83bafa4867ba16368e58f36e8311e9591e68f4) (09 Jul 2015) by [Karthik Nayak (`KarthikNayak`)](https://github.com/KarthikNayak).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9958dd8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9958dd8685a0a8b3d6ecdd07e35d8ecb22b304a7), 05 Oct 2015)</sup>

> Some features from "`git tag -l`" and "`git branch -l`" have been made
>   available to "`git for-each-ref`" so that eventually the unified
>   implementation can be shared across all three, in a follow-up
>   series or two.

```
* kn/for-each-tag-branch:
  for-each-ref: add '--contains' option
  ref-filter: implement '--contains' option
  parse-options.h: add macros for '--contains' option
  parse-option: rename parse_opt_with_commit()
  for-each-ref: add '--merged' and '--no-merged' options
  ref-filter: implement '--merged' and '--no-merged' options
  ref-filter: add parse_opt_merge_filter()
  for-each-ref: add '--points-at' option
  ref-filter: implement '--points-at' option
```

---

Note that starting Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), `git for-each-ref --no-contains <SHA1>` is finally supported!

See [commit 7505769](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75057691beb804e804df21992ae55d50ffc36f92), [commit 783b829](https://github.com/git/git/commit/783b829287952ec42bf89d9ca42fc6c51d7d0143), [commit ac3f5a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac3f5a346860b824e083c5d305757c3260565475), [commit 1e0c3b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e0c3b680c6e7b37fc51bd69a410af01897a4f94), [commit 6a33814](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a338149f623f493525324bc0f8d7bb9257cb840), [commit c485b24](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c485b24c427254fe36c2c6cc970519b797abd6bc), [commit eab98ee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eab98ee5ab84def96012f115a8e10571c6e24e4e), [commit bf74804](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf748049f53cea3662b02d87cc91d44a0164e588) (24 Mar 2017), [commit 7ac04f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ac04f1398c4e854cb585bd289ee4fe921984bbd), [commit 682b29f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/682b29f90d7e049c24f3821d49599dceb4aeb758), [commit 4612edc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4612edc639e8c7c15420960a92efa609e92ab9a7), [commit b643827](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b643827b9443deadaa5804998116107953f8b42f) (23 Mar 2017), and [commit 17d6c74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17d6c744dc0d5ed4cd0f228da14239ea2654f05b), [commit 8881d35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8881d35cace41604dba72c1b6b5ab5a59e0c2b94), [commit b084060](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b084060921d6403164e8dee506de787d017569c3), [commit 0488792](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0488792d2e56bfe38be6ea7f5456bd3286c807b8) (21 Mar 2017) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d1d3d46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1d3d46146e1256efe8ad2a2bb0dd877a738c07d), 11 Apr 2017)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing built in [**Edit**, Oct 2015: there is now, see [VonC's new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32987802/1256452)], but using `git branch -a --contains` and `git tag --contains` should get you all the references you would normally find "interesting".

There is a (non-built-in) way to find all such references.  Whenever you ask about "all references", you should look at [`git for-each-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html).  It allows you to iterate over all references, or some subset of all:

```
$ git for-each-ref
996b0fdbb4ff63bfd880b3901f054139c95611cf commit refs/heads/master
740c281d21ef5b27f6f1b942a4f2fc20f51e8c7e commit refs/remotes/origin/maint
996b0fdbb4ff63bfd880b3901f054139c95611cf commit refs/remotes/origin/master
7327a17171fc87d5f8f5c790eb1ba1d0e031482d commit refs/remotes/origin/next
[... snip]
efe35e936c6c32a7630086a84b2c3b3471ea534f tag    refs/tags/v2.0.1
b4463ead04f1801104502ea087dbb6bdd21b4ef1 tag    refs/tags/v2.0.2
3c81e95201ece182e799709c91b15a3501919d26 tag    refs/tags/v2.0.3
```

(in this case, I have run `git for-each-refs` on the repository for git itself, with no additional arguments, so it produces the default output).

All that you have to do now is to run the `--contains` detector on the raw reference.  While there is no plumbing command that has this as a verb, `--contains` is easily expressed as a test in [`git merge-base`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html), using `--is-ancestor`.  As the [`git branch` documentation notes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html), `--contains` simply tests whether the branch-tip—the SHA-1 shown above on the left of a `refs/heads/` or `refs/remotes/` reference—is a descendent of the specified commit.  "Is a descendent of" is really the same test as "is an ancestor of", with the arguments swapped:

```
$ git branch --contains 996b0fd^
* master
$ git rev-parse 996b0fd^
6da748a7cebe3911448fabf9426f81c9df9ec54f
```

Since `master` is `996b0fd...`, `--contains` matches for both `996b0fd` and its first parent `6da748a...`, so we can tell if we have our `git merge-base --is-ancestor` arguments the right way around:

```
$ git merge-base --is-ancestor 6da748a 996b0fd && echo ok
ok
```

Note that `996b0fd` is considered an ancestor of itself:

```
$ git merge-base --is-ancestor 996b0fd 996b0fd && echo ok
ok
```

So all you need to do is string together a `git for-each-ref` and a shell command or loop that runs `git merge-base --is-ancestor`.

Comment: Yes, I thought that there is no build-in command. I solved it using an alias that can take a parameter and added my answer. Since yours is detailed I will accept :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and `git for-each-ref --contains <SHA1>` was not enough for me because it only seems to list the *current* ref.  I used the following script to iterate over the reflogs, and used the `merge-base` trick from the answer above to do the `--contains` check:

```bash
SEARCH_FOR=<SHA1>

for refname in `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)'`; do
    for old in `git reflog --pretty='format:%H' $refname`; do
        git merge-base --is-ancestor $SEARCH_FOR $old && echo "FOUND reference from ref $refname / $old!"
    done
done
```