# programmatically check for unconnected branches

Tags: git

I'm having numerous (~200) git repositories, some of them containing *unconnected* (e.g. orphaned) branches.

I would like to cleanup those unconnected branches (e.g. merging them together if possible), but need to find out which repositories are actually affected.

Since the histories of the repositories are probably long and convoluted, inspecting each repo with a graphical tool such as `gitk` is *not* an option.

Instead I need a programmatic way, to find out which branches are detached (e.g. from `HEAD`).

Comment: in order to improve my questions (future and present), I would be interested why *you* downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using words that git defines in one particular fashion (such as "orphan" and "detached") in a way that differs from git's usage.  I *think* I know what you mean, but for clarity here's a brief diagram of a repo with three branches and two root commits:

```
A <- B <- C   <-- branch1

         F    <-- branch2
       /
D <- E
       \
         G    <-- branch3
```

Which (if any) of these three branches are "orphaned"?  Perhaps branch1 is an orphan, with branch2 and branch3 being "non-orphaned"; but perhaps branch1 is the only "non-orphan" and branch2 and branch3 are "orphaned".

Anyway, however you choose to define it, your task is to find the roots you want to claim are "orphaned", probably by finding all root commits:

```
git rev-list --all --max-parents=0
```

and then deciding which of those are "orphan-y" vs which are "non-orphan-y".  Then, for each branch, see which roots they contain.  Note that one branch may contain multiple roots.  For instance, in the example above, if you decide that root `A` is "orphan-y", you might fix this by merging a commit from branch2, e.g.:

```
A <- B <- C - M   <-- branch1
            /
         F    <-- branch2
       /
D <- E
       \
         G    <-- branch3
```

Now branch1 contains both roots, and therefore is "non-orphan-y".

(Of course, if this isn't what you meant by using the words "orphan" and "detached", this answer is probably not very useful.)

(To do this programmatically, you still have to define what it means for a branch to have an "orphan" root vs one that has a "non-orphan" root, but after that, it's just a matter of using `git branch --contains` on every branch, or the new `--contains` option of `git for-each-ref`.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24993772/1256452) and its answers.)

Comment: thanks; indeed by "orphaned" i meant "unconnected"; i'm aware that if i have two unconnected parts in my repo, both can be seen equivalent, so it's probably futile trying to find out which branches are unconnected (however, in my original question i tried to define "orphaned" as being unconnected from the `default` branch, e.g. *master*); in any case, it would help me, if I could identify the *repositories* containing disconnected branches. updated the question

Comment: You can read `HEAD` (use `git symbolic-ref` to read it) and see which branch, if any, is current in that repo.  You could then define "roots reachable from this branch" as "non-orphan-y".  Any other branches that contain only roots that are *not* contained in that branch, would qualify; and any repo that has such, would qualify.